# pySDL2 Display without End Loop

Tags: python, graphics, sdl, pysdl2

In every pySLD2 example I've found, I've seen a loop at the end of the code to keep the window open until closure.  For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
The code is placed into public domain
by anatoly techtonik <techtonik@gmail.com>
"""
import sdl2
import sdl2.ext as lib

lib.init()

window = lib.Window('', size=(300, 100))
window.show()

renderer = lib.Renderer(window)
renderer.draw_point([10,10], lib.Color(255,255,255))
renderer.present()

####Specifically this loop####
running = True
while running:
  for e in lib.get_events():
    if e.type == sdl2.SDL_QUIT:
      running = False
      break
    if e.type == sdl2.SDL_KEYDOWN:
      if e.key.keysym.sym == sdl2.SDLK_ESCAPE:
        running = False
        break
```

All event handlers I've seen have been blocking.  Is there a way, like I have seen done in standard SDL, to simply call **initialization and updating functions on a window that stays open**.  I am writing to write this as an external library that I can call independently from any project.

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: As per request for a way to do this in standard SDL, [this](https://github.com/aacoppa/Graphics_Engine_America/blob/master/src/screen.c) works.  Just call the init function to set up the screen and it will stay until you close it.

Comment: `"like I have seen done in standard SDL!"` What do you mean? Can you show us the actual code you are talking about?

Comment: See above edit, Olevegard.

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting the example - this is an additional hook (screen.c) to be set up in the main loop.

SDL uses the main loop approach to deal with events, update the window display, etc. Yes, there is a way to work around that. Create your very own window and use whatever approach to keep it open, get the window handle via the SDL_SysWM* functions and update the window's display buffer.

This however involves some glue code and also requires you to do the window handling on your own.